# Best way to poll a database table for updates from a java web application

Tags: java, database, polling

I am fairly new to java programming and have a use case where I need to constantly poll about 15 values in a database table for changes from a java web service. If any of the values change, I need to pick up all 15 values from the database and feed my business logic with the real time values. What is the best way to implement this? I was thinking of running a polling thread from within the web service but not sure if that is the correct approach. I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: You could use `setInterval()` from the client side i.e. javascript to call a webservice every 15 seconds and update your values.

Comment: Constant polling doesn't seem usual for a web service. Why not just get the values upon request, each time your service is called? What are the volumes you're expecting for your service?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using javascript/ajax:

```
function refreshData()
{
    //ajax call here call your webservice
    //do updates real time
}
setInterval(refreshData, 15000); //call your webservice every 15 seconds
```

Another option to avoid any overlap from `async` ajax calls (if your function takes longer than 15 seconds to run (unlikely)):

```
function refreshData()
{
    //ajax call here call your webservice
    //do updates real time
    setTimeout(refreshData, 15000);
}
refreshData();
```